# UICollectionViewCell Auto Size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Example, we have a `UICollectionView` with full width of the screen. This has 3 100 x 100px cells. On my iPad it will spread these across the full width leaving large gaps between each cell, naturally smaller gaps on a device with a smaller screen, i.e. an iPhone.

Is it possible to have the cell width automatically change depending on screen width to eliminate these gaps? I only want the expected, as set, 5px spacing.

Comment: So do you want 3 larger cells, or more than 3 cells when viewing on an iPad? The former would require returning the size of the cell in the UICollectionViewDelegate while the later should be handled by the UICollectionViewLayout more or less automatically.

Comment: Look at my answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28620374/set-override-padding-in-uicollectionview-between-cells/28621804#28621804. This is in Swift, but it should be easy enough to translate to objective-c. It's just a matter of setting the itemSize based on the space you have after allowing for any gaps you want.

Comment: If I had more than 3 cells, it may fill the row and move to a new row. Or if these are still not enough cells to fill the screens width (1 row), then the gaps would just be smaller. So what I am trying to achieve is, no matter how many cells on screen on in a row, the cells always stretch across the screen so that the only gap between them is the set spacing. I think @rdelmar may have the answer, I'll have a play with that solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step 1:** Implement **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout**

**Step 2:** Use delegate method of **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout**.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    return CGSizeMake((UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width-10)/3,120); //use height whatever you wants.
}
```

**Step 3:** Go to **XIB** or **StoryBoard** where you have your **CollectionView**.

**Step 4:** In **XIB** or **StoryBoard** where you have your **CollectionView** click on CollectionView.

**Step 5:** Go to InterfaceBuilder, then in second last tab (ie: Size Inspector) set **Min Spacing**

For Cells = 5

For Lines = 5

That it.